# SwiftUI SF Symbols Accessibility

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility, sf-symbols

I'm trying to make my app more accessible for customers who are blind or low-vision. To minimize unnecessary information I am trying to remove VoiceOver for decorative images. In the following example VoiceOver reads "clock.arrow.circlepath"; which is maybe not very helpful.

For images it is possible to disable VoiceOver by using

```swift
Image(decorative: "image")
```

How can I do this for a system image (an SF Symbol)?

```swift
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "clock.arrow.circlepath")
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
        .foregroundColor(.orange)
        .padding(.trailing)
    Text(LocalizedStringKey(stringLiteral: "DeleteHistory"))
    Spacer()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible solution is to hide accessibility element, like

```
    Image(systemName: "clock.arrow.circlepath")
        .accessibility(hidden: true)
```

Tested with Xcode 13beta / iOS15

Comment: Thank you Asperi, this works. I knew there has to be an easy solution. The decorative parameter leads me to the wrong way :-)